# Performance: Fastest way to check if a List<String> contains a specific String

Tags: java, performance, iteration

In the program I'm writing on, I'll have to check if a List (actually I can replace the type of Collection if necessary) contains a specific String.

Is this the fastest way to do it?

```
private boolean containsItem(List<String> list, String path) {
        for (String s : list) {
            if (s.equals(path)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

I'm asking for performance only, as this operation may happen a couple of thousand times in a row.

Comment: Use a HashSet to improve performance, and instead of your method, use `set.contains(path)`.

Comment: not to mention: list.contains(path) would be better suited than this code.

Comment: and contains method of set.

Comment: @Eran: Well, a `HashSet` will improve *retrieval* performance. But naturally there's a cost in terms of *insert* performance.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, given that the OP said he wants to run the search for `a couple of thousand times in a row`, I figured it would be more efficient to store the data in a `HashSet`. Of course if inserts happen more often than retrievals, that may not be true.

Comment: @ParkerHalo: What makes you think the built-in would be *slower* than a manual loop in the code calling it? At worst it'll be a tie. At best the implementation can work directly with the data structures rather than through the API and save a fair bit of work.

Comment: @Eran: Yes. I'm just saying, a HashSet doesn't just magically improve performance. If reads outweigh writes, it will, but that's not the same as a bald "will improve performance" statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to check if a List<String> contains a unique String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307549/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-liststring-contains-a-unique-string)

Answer (score 0):

If you list is const(unmodifiable or your never change it after construct). You can build that list to a Trie tree[Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), and perform search using the tree. It's fast and can find words(not only extract equal)